# WiX custom license file: setup shows links with < >

Tags: hyperlink, licensing, wix, wix3.5

I created a WiX 3.5 setup with a custom license file by putting this into the `.wxs` file:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="License.rtf" />
```

This works perfectly and the link is displayed when I run the created `.msi` file.
(I'm using the [`WixUI_InstallDir` Dialog Set](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_installdir.htm))

Now I want to put a hyperlink into the license file.
I just put the link into the file by opening it in WordPad and pasting `http://mylink.com` (WordPad turns it into a hyperlink automatically).

When I compile that in WiX, the license agreement dialog shows the link like this:

```
<http://mylink.com>
```

I noticed that this seems to relate to WordPad creating a hyperlink automatically (see above).
When I remove the `http://` part from the link in the license file, WordPad doesn't recognize it as a link anymore and in the compiled `.msi` file, the `<` and `>` in the license agreement dialog go away.

Any ideas how I can get rid of the additional `<` and `>`, except putting the link into the license file without the `http://` part?

---

*EDIT:*

Okay, maybe I didn't think enough when I used the word "hyperlink".
What I actually meant was: It does not have to be an actual *clickable* hyperlink.
I just want the adress of my web page to be displayed at the top of the license file.

I'm perfectly fine if it's just the URL as text (not clickable), but I want it to be displayed as I entered it, and not with `< >`.
The problem is that WordPad automatically turns any URL into a hyperlink as soon as I enter it, so I have no idea how to get the license agreement dialog to treat it as normal text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't support hyperlinks in the scrollable text control. This is why the link is not displayed correctly. Even if it was, nothing would happen when you click it because Windows Installer doesn't handle this event.

A hyperlink in a scrollable text control works only if you use an external UI which handles it.

Edit:

If you just want to display some text as a link, the usual approach is make it blue and underlined. As you already noticed Windows Installer doesn't show conventional hyperlinks correctly.

If you want to show a link as normal text, simply open the RTF file with a normal text editor (for example notepad.exe) and remove the hyperlink markers. Just follow the normal text formatting and you will easily spot the markers you want to remove.

Comment: okay, maybe I shouldn't have used the word "hyperlink". I edited my question!

Comment: The text doesn't even have to be a hyperlink. I just want `http://mylink.com` as plain text, exactly as I entered it. The actual problem is how to make WordPad **not** turn this into a link automatically (or how to make Windows installer ignore the link)

Comment: Perfect, that's the solution! I found a way that's even easier than removing the hyperlink markers manually: I opened the file in WordPad and removed the `h` from `http://...`. This causes WordPad to automatically remove the hyperlink, so after that I just have to use the text editor to put the `h` back in. Works like a charm!