# How to include hyperlink license in Wix's Product.wxs

Tags: wix

How to put the license's hyperlink in the Product.wxs?

I only notice that there are these code below:

```
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="path\License.rtf" />
```

for including the license from the rtf document.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that this is possible

[WiX custom license file: setup shows links with < >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633617/wix-custom-license-file-setup-shows-links-with)

MSI does not support hyperlinks. You can modify the text to look like a link but it won't actually work.

That said, the WiX Standard Bootstrapper does support hyperlinks

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_license.html